# PHP - Why create DateTime with relative format of year does not work

Tags: php, date, datetime

I don't understand why create a date for last or next year works:

```
new DateTime('first day of January last year');
```

But not for another year :

```
new DateTime('first day of January 2 years ago');
```

I got:

> Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (first day of January 2 year ago) at position 23 (y): The timezone could not be found in the database

Or maybe I don't write it correctly. Nothing in the PHP docs on the page of relative format say that does not work with year.

Anyone has a explanation?

Comment: `new DateTime(2 years ago first day of January');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the order wrong. This works:

```
new DateTime('2 years ago first day of january');
```

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` is an exceptionally picky class.

```
new DateTime('first day of January +2 years'); // works fine
new DateTime('first day of January -2 years'); // doesn't work at all
```

In the second case, changing the position of the predicates gets the right result:

```
new DateTime('-2 years first day of January'); // 2015-01-01
```

This is also the case for your example string:

```
echo (new DateTime('2 years ago first day of january'))->format('Y-m-d');
// 2015-01-01
```

This may or may not be useful, depending on where that string is coming from.

To avoid any ambiguity, or just for clarity, it can sometimes be better to break this down into two operations:

```
new DateTime('first tuesday this year'))->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-11-28 (what?)
new DateTime('january first tuesday'))->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-01-24 (nope)

$dt = (new DateTime('first day of January'))->modify('next tuesday');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-01-03 (Woohoo!)
```